# What is the best way to use sdo_relate in oralce spatial 10g?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle10g, spatial

I'm using sdo_relate Operator of Oracle spatial in a client-server environment to query two tables each has thousands of geometry objects. I apply a condition in the where cluase to pass only one object to the so-called query-window.

Using '/*+ ordered */' hint and the required order of tables in the from clause( as documented in Oracle Spatial reference) i get a bad Performance:

```
 SELECT /*+ ORDERED */  A.someAttr FROM  Polygons A,lines B  WHERE
   B.id=someValue AND sdo_relate(B.geom,A.geom,
             'mask=anyinteract') = 'TRUE';  --6 Min!
```

I thinkt it is the way around, because without the ordered hint, it takes 50 Sec. (still need to be optimized) 
Any way, it seems that the spatial documentation is worng!
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_operat.htm#i78531

Any one has had such an experience, look Forward your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing is that your query is incorrectly written. In all spatial operators, the *first* column is that from the table you search, the *second* one is your query window. So rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT A.someAttr 
FROM Polygons A,lines B  
WHERE B.id=someValue 
AND sdo_relate(A.geom,B.geom,'mask=anyinteract') = 'TRUE';
```

or simpler:

```
SELECT A.someAttr 
FROM Polygons A,lines B  
WHERE B.id=someValue 
AND sdo_anyinteract(A.geom,B.geom) = 'TRUE';
```

This will be much faster than the 50 seconds you indicate. And the hint is not necessary at all.

Assuming you want to do the reverse operation (= search for all LINES that intersect a given POLYGON), then you would write this:

```
SELECT A.someAttr 
FROM Polygons A,lines B  
WHERE A.id=someValue 
AND sdo_anyinteract(B.geom,A.geom) = 'TRUE';
```

In other words you need to order the arguments to SDO_ANYINTERACT in such a way that the **first** is the name of the column you **search** and the **second** is your **search window**.

The ordering of the tables in the *from* clause is not important, neither is the ordering of the predicates in the *where* clause: the database optimizer will produce the same query plan.

The only reason for ordering the tables in the *where* clause is if you use the /*+ order */ hint to get the optimiser to perform the join in the order the tables are listed. But this is unnecessary here (and may even have negative effects).

The simple rule is this: do not use any hints - unless you know you have a problem and you know for a fact that using some specific hints will solve that. Never use hints just because you think them necessary. The optimizer is clever enough to produce the proper plan and hints are used only in rare occasions when it does not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I Need then to write a.id=someValue.

Comment: Huh ? Why would you want to do that ? Your example is about searching for all POLYGONS (A) that intersect a given LINE (B) identified by its ID.